# How to set value to input tag from JSON in PUG?

Tags: json, input, pug

I Have code like this:

```
- var data ={val1: 'a', val2: 2}
input(type="text", value = "#{data.val1}")
p #{data.val2}
```

and gess what i've got

```
<input type="text" value="#{data.val1}">
<p>2</p>
```

but i need to it be like this

```
<input type="text" value="a">
<p>2</p>
```

What do i do wrong?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Using pug syntax your should be:

```
- var data = {val1: 'a', val2: 2};
input(type="text" value=data.val1)
p= data.val2
```